# mysql-multi: how to select instance by port (instead of socket)?

Tags: mysql, sockets, centos7

I have a second mysql instance running with mysqld_multi on port 3307. If connecting to it by port i get the databases from the first instance, like connecting to 3306. If i connect by socket i get the correct databases from the second instance. I need this second instance for a test environment, so i need to select the instance and it's storage/datadir by port. Can you help me?

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld_multi]  
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe  
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin  
user       = root  
password   = something  

[mysqld]  
datadir=/var/lib/mysql  
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock  
symbolic-links=0  
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES  

[mysqld2]  
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe  
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin  
socket     = /var/lib/mysql2/tmp/mysql2.sock  
port       = 3307  
pid-file   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid  
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql2  
language   = /usr/share/mysql/english  
user       = mysql  

[mysqld_safe]  
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log  
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**systemctl status mysqld**

```
mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server  
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)  
   Active: active (running) since Mo 2016-02-08 12:54:40 CET; 24h ago  
  Process: 6901 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post  code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
  Process: 6889 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
 Main PID: 6900 (mysqld_safe)  
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service  
           ├─6900 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe  
           └─7062 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

**mysqld_multi report**

```
WARNING: Log file disabled. Maybe directory or file isn't writable?  
mysqld_multi log file version 2.16; run: Di Feb  9 13:54:19 2016  
Reporting MySQL servers  
MySQL server from group: mysqld2 is running
```

**Connect to first instance**

```
$ mysql -u root -p  

mysql> show databases;  
+--------------------+  
| Database           |  
+--------------------+  
| information_schema |  
| mysql              |  
| performance_schema |  
| portal             |  
| swfl               |  
+--------------------+  
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)  

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';  
+---------------+-------+  
| Variable_name | Value |  
+---------------+-------+  
| port          | 3306  |  
+---------------+-------+  
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

**Connect to second instance by port**

```
$ mysql -P 3307 -u root -p  

mysql> show databases;  
+--------------------+  
| Database           |  
+--------------------+  
| information_schema |  
| mysql              |  
| performance_schema |  
| portal             |  
| swfl               |  
+--------------------+  
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)  

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';  
+---------------+-------+  
| Variable_name | Value |  
+---------------+-------+  
| port          | 3306  |  
+---------------+-------+  
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

**Connect to second instance by socket**

```
$ mysql -S /var/lib/mysql2/tmp/mysql2.sock -u root -p  

mysql> show variables like 'port';  
+---------------+-------+  
| Variable_name | Value |  
+---------------+-------+  
| port          | 3307  |  
+---------------+-------+  
1 row in set (0,00 sec)  

mysql> show databases;  
+--------------------+  
| Database           |  
+--------------------+   
| information_schema |  
| mysql              |  
| performance_schema |  
| tmp                |  
+--------------------+  
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**Server**

CentOS 7 with MySQL 5.6.25

Comment: See doc.: `To cause the port number to be used, invoke the program in either of these ways: shell> mysql --port=13306 --host=127.0.0.1 / shell> mysql --port=13306 --protocol=TCP`. [4.2.2 Connecting to the MySQL Server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html).

Comment: Great, thank you. I tried it with phpmyadmin before and had tcp set as connection_type, but now using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost it works!